# Automatic thresholding in motion detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a project which requires to detect motion. I am currently using BackgroundSubstractionCNT class in opencv for this purpose. The above algorithm returns a binary image where white pixels represent the moving objects. I am having some trouble in defining a threshold which makes decision if there was a motion or it is just noise. At present I am using a threshold of 5%. Is there any algorithm or process which can adjust this threshold automatically or predict this threshold on the basis of the sequence?

Below is the partial code for it:

```
def main():    
    minPixelStability = 30
    useHistory = False
    maxPixelStability = 60
    isParallel = False
    bs_cnt = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorCNT(minPixelStability, useHistory, maxPixelStability, isParallel)
    output_frame = bs_cnt.apply(current_frame)
```

This is the detection function:

```
def detect_motion(output_frame):
    total_white_pixels = np.sum(output_frame > 100)
    # print(total_white_pixels)
    motion = None
    if(total_white_pixels > 0.05*output_frame.shape[0]*output_frame.shape[1]):
        motion = True
    else:           
        motion = False
```

Resolution of image = 300 x 200

Type of sensor = USB camera

Objects to be detected = Any moving object(living and non-living)

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add more information to comment on.

Comment: Can you please mention what additional information is required?

Comment: "I am working on a project which requires to detect motion" -> This seems *very* broad (type of sensor? resolution ? type and size of objects ?). You should also add the piece of code used to instantiate the `BackgroundSubstractionCNT` class

Comment: @GabrielDevillers Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the question with a code snippet. Let me know if you need anything more.